# How to get rubber thing to deform as mini gun moves up and down instead of moving with it?

Tags: animation, armature, physics, vertex-groups, vertex-weights

[image]

How to get rubber thing to deform as the mini gun moves up and down instead of moving with it in Blender 4.0.2.

I used automatic weights it is not working.

Please watch whole gif

[Video](https://youtu.be/_PpkScq5aE0)

do i need soft body physic?

Comment: Hello and welcome. Please don't post the same question more than once. If your previous question was put on hold, address the raised issues by editing it so it can be reopened rather than post a new one, otherwise see [What should I do if no one answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/no-one-answers)

Answer (score 4):

No, you don't need soft body physics. Just another bone or two, I guess. Has the "plunger"/rubber thing a bone? If you only have 1 bone you cannot control the deformation properly.

Add two more bones, make sure the barrel of the gun is only influenced be its own bone. In the example, you see the "gun" is blue when I select the *lower_rubber_bone* vertex group. It's complete red (=full weights) when the *handle_bone* vertex group is selected. Each bone has a *Vertex Group* with the same name as the bone.

The rubber thing should be influenced by both bones all three bones. Checkout the *Weight Paint* mode, if *With Automatic Weights* does not provide a perfect result. The barrel will most likely bend as a result. You can fix this manually by painting the weights.

Note that you also can assign and remove vertices from a vertex group in *Edit* mode. There you can also hide geometry that are in your way. This hides them in *Weight Painting* mode, too.

The root bone *lower_rubber_bone* in the example can rotate, scale and move the whole object in *Pose* mode. No need to move the armature in *Object* mode (but sometimes you want/need to).

[image: weight painting]